# RuntimeError: Event loop is closed (and I don't know why)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I know, this has been asked maybe a hundred times, but I still cannot figure out why this always draws an error at the end.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def read_index_page():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://some/api/url') as resp:
            print(resp.status)

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    task = loop.create_task(read_index_page())

    await asyncio.gather(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This reports the well known runtime error for the event look is closed. I run this code on a Windows 10 machine.

From my point of view I do things right but I'm a totally beginner in using asyncio. So, please be gentle. :)

Regards, Thomas

Comment: Try replacing `loop.create_task(read_index_page())` with `loop.create_task(read_index_page)`.

Comment: You probably stumbled upon [this bug](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324) which shows with aiohttp on Windows. As an aside, note that creating a task and then awaiting it is unnecessary. Also, `await asyncio.gather(just_one_arg)` is the same as `await just_one_arg`. In summary, your main() should just consist of `await read_index_page()`. (Which won't fix your problem, which is in aiohttp.)

Comment: Well, that may explain it. It really drove me nuts because I knew my code is right. Yeah, I know that await asyncio.gather() is a bit too much for just one coroutine, however the script had more code lines before and cut it down to that minimum just to see if I have my stupid day or not. :) Thanks for your advice, going to start my Virtualbox with Debian.

Comment: @enzo this won't work sind create_task expects a coroutine not a function. This raises a TypeError, additionally you won't be able to hand over arguments. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set another loop implementation for your app, on the other hand I should say that I have no error on my Windows 10 Home, tested on Python 3.6 (with Aiohttp 3.4.4) and Python 3.9.  (with Aiohttp 3.7.4.post())

```py
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

URL = "http://..."


async def send_req(session: ClientSession):
    async with session.get(URL) as resp:
        if resp.status == 200:
            r = await resp.json()
            print(r)
        else:
            print(resp.status)


async def main():
    # check what loop is really running in our Main Thread now
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    print(loop)
    # no need to create ClientSession for all send_req, you need only one ClientSession
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        # asyncio gather creates tasks itself, no need to create tasks outside
        await asyncio.gather(*[send_req(session) for _ in range(8)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # set another loop implementation:
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using `WindowsSelectEventPolicy` seems to solve my issue. Once again, thanks for pointing to this!